# Javascript:document.write("hello world") works at first but

Tags: javascript, document.write

Javascript:document.write("hello world") works at first but if you change the text it does not work for the next text.

To reproduce:
In your address bar:

1. Type http://nazmulweb.com  or any other url
2. After loading the page, type Javascript:document.write("hello world")
3. Browser will show "hello world", isn't it?
4. Then type javascript:document.write('hello stackoverflow users!')

This time the browser doesn't update the text. What can be the reason?

---

"What is my target?"

---

I am using the following code to write in an Iframe

```
function writeInIframe(data){   
var previewWindow=$("pwFrame").contentWindow;
if (previewWindow.document) {
    previewWindow.document.open();
    previewWindow.document.write(data); 
    previewWindow.document.close();
}
}
```

For the first time data is properly shown in the Iframe but later on, newly data is not updated in the Iframe.

Comment: Confused... where on the page to type `Javascript:document.write("hello world")`

Comment: What is your actual goal here? Maybe there's a better way to achieve what you want. There aren't many valid reasons for entering javascript directly into the address bar. Also what browser are you using, Firefox behaves as you would expect (I didn't start by clicking your link though).

Comment: @Starx - In the browsers address bar

Comment: @Starx,Please type in the addressbar

Comment: @Fishcake, I would like to write in an Iframe, using contentWindow.document.write

Comment: @Fishcake, sorry to write an unknown url "nazmulweb", you can follow any url too.

Comment: @Hoque No problem. As I say though it does work for me, after following your steps my browser (Firefox) contains the text "hello worldhello stackoverflow users!"

Comment: I just tried it using IE developer toolbar. It is working fine, if you are closing the document object after the first write else it will keep appending to the previous string. In firebug console it will not work since `document.write` will override the firebug console also.

Comment: @Fishcake, In FireFox, the text has been appended which I did not try at first. I was working with IE 8 and in that it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write):

> Writing to a document that has already
>   loaded without calling document.open()
>   will automatically perform a
>   document.open call. Once you have
>   finished writing, it is recommended to
>   call document.close(), to tell the
>   browser to finish loading the page.
>   The text you write is parsed into the
>   document's structure model.

Comment: I did so, but for the second time when I tried to write again, it did not update the content.

Comment: Which browser? On FF the behaviour seems to be correct to me. The second document.write result is appended to the first one.

Comment: using Internet Explorer Version 8

Comment: Might try playing with innerHTML instead. Seems strange (though I would never rely on document.write anyways).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write another statement you have to write:

```
window.document.write("<div>Hello World!</div>");
```

and then write the other one with the same way

```
window.document.write("<div>hello stackoverflow users!</div>");
```

But in the first statement you can directly write

```
document.write("Hello World!");
```

Without using the `div`, `p` or `h1` tags (this works with the first statement only).
And if you started with

```
document.write("<div>Hello World!</div>");
```

you could write

```
document.write("hello stackoverflow users!");
```

I hope that my explaining was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what's the problem..
It depends on what event you call this function. Show the code. If you want to load it at every page load you should put it like this:

```
<body onload="yourfunction()">
```

or attach it to window.onload. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: I want to write contents in an IFrame using contentWindow.document.write